# How to get the product type?

Tags: magento2, product, product-attribute

I'm creating a new module in Magento 2. I try to get product information in the phtml file. I have get successfully **entity_id** and **product name** information. but when I get product type information is getting wrong. The following code used.

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_product'); //get current product

echo $product->getId() . '<br/>';
echo $product->getName() . '<br/>';
echo $product->getProductType() . '<br/>'; //getting wrong product type
```

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You should try

```
$product->getTypeId()
```

It will return **configurable**, **simple**, **grouped**, **virtual**, **downloadable** and **bundle**.

Comment: Does it work for collection and product object both?

Comment: it also returns other types like grouped , virtual , ...

Comment: there is also `bundle`

Answer (score 1):

For ordered product list, from order collection we can use **$item->getProductType()** to get the Product type.

Sample code set

```
<?php 
......
foreach ($orders->getAllItems() as $item) {
  echo $item->getName()."-".$item->getProductType();
}
......
?>
```

Tested with **magento 2.4.5_p1**

Answer (score -6):

Try this :

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_product'); //get current product

$product->getTypeId() // it will return the product type
```